# how to fix slide interval time (between slides) in cycle 2 jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

just iam using cycle 2 jquery plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/.

the below mentioned code is working fine.But i could not able to fix the slide interval time between slides. how to fix the slide interval time. anyone can advice..

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-speed="800">
   <img src="images/Slider/Industrial-Fats_FI-Banner.png">
   <img src="images/Slider/01.jpg">
   <img src="images/Slider/02.jpg">
   <img src="images/Slider/03.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute data-cycle-timeout="9000" in your div. you can update 9000 to whatever you want.